# What is og_phrase(Open Graph phrase) in facebook photo api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

There is a parameter named "og_phrase" in Facebook Open Graph API documentation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos

There is no explanation for that parameter.
Web search doesn't return anything.